# REST API for HPE iLO. IP address

Tags: rest

I'm new to REST API for HPE servers.
I used to SSH to a VMware host, to get it's iLO Ip configuration in case it was somehow unknown.
I could do that using "./hponcfg -w /tmp/ilo-conf.txt (writes configuration to file)"
hponcfg is depricated, and now REST API is to be used, so I do like:

1. I SSH to the VMware host and login.
2. Run "/opt/tools/ilorest" which takes me to iLOREST>
3. From there I can type "ethernet" and get a lot of information, also the iLO IP address, but it's difficult to read the format as it is hundreds of lines with other kind of information like Host IP Address, timezones, etc.

Any command I can use that gives me only the information I need (iLO IP address)